# What is this second login screen?

Tags: login-screen

Before being presented with the **actual login screen**, I am presented with another *additional login screen*.

What is this second login screen?

### **Actual login screen:**

[image]

### *Additional login screen:*

[image]

Related bug report is [#1577110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1577110).

Comment: Try removing your .Xauthority.  Go to a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and type `mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_2016-07-02`.  Then run `sudo service lightdm restart` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: And BTW, the additional isn't technically a login screen; it's an unlock screen.

Comment: You could also run `chown -R user:user ~/.dbus`, replacing user with your username.

Comment: I also had this second unlock screen once after Unity crashed and kicked me out of my session.

Comment: @anonymous2: Let the user's environment tell you what the ownership should be: `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.dbus` (and use `sudo` to insist on the ownership change).

Comment: @anonymous2 thank you! Your first comment solved my problem! :-)

Comment: Oh no, the problem just returned...

Comment: Did you use the sudo command between the time that it started working and started working?

Comment: I can't say with certainty but it's very likely, yes.

Comment: Check the ownership on your .Xauthority.  Is it owned by root?

Comment: No, it's owned by the correct user.

Comment: What are it's permissions?

Comment: Looks like a glitch , GNOME's lock screen thinks your session is locked or something

Comment: `-rw------- 1 orschiro orschiro 49 Jul  3 13:05 .Xauthority`.

Comment: I assume it's better to continue the discussion at [Bug #1577110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1577110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remove your .Xauthority.

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_2016-07-03
sudo service lightdm restart
```

**You could also try just changing it's ownership:**

```
sudo chown user:user .Xauthority
sudo service lightdm restart
```

...replacing `user` with your username.