# I lose my working session randomly (16.04)

Tags: crash, docker

**EDIT 14/3 10PM**
I have been attempting to see if docker is the cause as I ran lots of stuff and it was the only process to trigger the crash. I tried to reinstall and clear it out

```
docker system prune -a --volumes
sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker.io
sudo curl -L ttps://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-uname -s-uname -m -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

But the error still happens. Here is the Kern.log of one of the crashes https://pastebin.com/jZDBa5gb

Memtest86 ran a pass and came back good. sudo dmidecode -t 1,2:

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
    SMBIOS 2.7 present.

    Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20217
    Version: Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P
    Serial Number: 1018244601447
    UUID: 8CB2CD8D-02A5-E311-9302-28D244654B6E
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_BI_IDEAPAD  
    Family: IDEAPAD

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: VIQY0Y1
    Version: 31900058STD
    Serial Number: YB02487327
    Asset Tag: No Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

**EDIT 13/3 11AM**

I can recreate this error consistently by bringing up a certain container in docker-compose in detached mode (run containers in the background). I have other projects that do not cause the error.

Also note if possibly related, mysteriously at some point in all the session crashes and a few restarts I also now have my lock screen loading correctly again. I have not tried to fix this or personally done anything I would expect to change this. I've since found this question that shows the login as I saw it (although the gnome grey one had a black background) [Strange lock screen on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871588/strange-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I quickly see what I believe to be fsck run, says clean, and then I need to login to a new session losing everything I was doing before. I'm not sure what to look at to fix this.

It feels more common if I leave my machine on for multiple days but that might be my mind playing tricks. Most recent session loss, I ran last reboot and it says 2 days ago.

```
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-88-generi Tue Mar 10 22:33   still running
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 running from USB SSD.

I recently updated chrome for the first time (I'm new to linux) and I lost my nice looking lock screen and figured that was lightDM messed up in the update and haven't worried but perhaps related. It popped up about GRUB and I said no changes or along them lines and the install contined. Chrome is now up to date and working. Bash history of installing chrome:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt list --installed | grep 'chrome'
sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

bluetooth is off on my laptop I just got this error on (see it in the log) but I have a wireless mouse at my desktop.

sudo less /var/log/syslog (verbose but hopefully I've caught the problem in this):

```
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude dbus[819]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name=
'org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session-binary[25678]: Entering running state
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (process:25999): indicator-applicat
ion-service-WARNING **: Unable to get watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatche
r'
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (process:25999): indicator-applicat
ion-service-WARNING **: Name Lost
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude gnome-session[25678]: (nautilus:25989): GLib-GObject-CRIT
ICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' f
ailed
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude snapd[26012]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and al
l features are available
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude snapd[26012]: daemon.go:338: started snapd/2.40 (series 1
6; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-88-generic.
Mar 12 22:22:08 maude systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Mar 12 22:22:09 maude dbus[819]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.f
reedesktop.locale1'
Mar 12 22:22:09 maude systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Mar 12 22:22:13 maude snapd[26012]: daemon.go:576: gracefully waiting for runni
ng hooks
Mar 12 22:22:13 maude snapd[26012]: daemon.go:578: done waiting for running hoo
ks
Mar 12 22:22:13 maude snapd[26012]: daemon stop requested to wait for socket ac
tivation
Mar 12 22:22:15 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes
of 2 users.
Mar 12 22:22:15 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervisi
ng 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.]
Mar 12 22:22:15 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: Successfully made thread 26204 of pro
cess 26128 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 10.
Mar 12 22:22:15 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes
of 2 users.
Mar 12 22:22:17 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: message repeated 12 times: [ Supervis
ing 9 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.]
Mar 12 22:22:17 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: Successfully made thread 26373 of pro
cess 26183 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 10.
Mar 12 22:22:17 maude rtkit-daemon[1278]: Supervising 10 threads of 4 processes
of 2 users.
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: (gnome-software:26000): As-WARNING
**: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/adam/.local/share/applications/mimea
pps.list.new file: cannot process file of type text/plain
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: (gnome-software:26000): As-WARNING
**: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/adam/.local/share/applications/mimea
pps.list file: cannot process file of type text/plain
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: (gnome-software:26000): As-WARNING
**: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/adam/.local/share/applications/mimea
pps.list.new file: cannot process file of type text/plain
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: (gnome-software:26000): As-WARNING
**: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/adam/.local/share/applications/mimea
pps.list file: cannot process file of type text/plain
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.504965:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(853)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.508653:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(862)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.541148:INFO:HandlerRen
dererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.545022:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(853)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.545095:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(862)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.772297:INFO:HandlerRen
dererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.774384:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(853)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.774444:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(862)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.822769:ERROR:gl_implem
entation.cc(280)] Failed to load /tmp/.mount_jetbraIeq6Xx/usr/share/jetbrains-to
olbox/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /tmp/.mount_jetbraIeq6Xx/usr/share/jetbrains-too
lbox/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or d
irectory
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.853511:ERROR:viz_main_
impl.cc(170)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.868778:INFO:HandlerRen
dererProcess.cpp(10)] HandlerRendererProcess disposed
Mar 12 22:22:19 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222219.870671:WARNING:gpu_pro
cess_host.cc(1205)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.204970:INFO:HandlerRen
dererProcess.cpp(15)] Started CEF-render process
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.373413:INFO:HandlerRen
dererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.380080:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(853)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.380159:ERROR:main_dele
gate.cc(862)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.384810:WARNING:gpu_pro
cess_host.cc(982)] Reinitialized the GPU process after a crash. The reported ini
tialization time was 0 ms
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.716879:INFO:CONSOLE(66
)] "Updated model size: 320041", source: qrc://ui/index.js (66)
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.741085:INFO:CONSOLE(66
)] "Initial model size: 320006", source: qrc://ui/index.js (66)
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.760034:INFO:CONSOLE(29
)] "`size`, `width` and `height` props are not recommended to use in Ring UI `Ic
on` component. The intrinsic sizes of SVG icon (`width` and `height` SVG attribu
tes) are used instead.
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: We strongly recommend to use icons
handcrafted for particular sizes. If your icon doesn't exist in the desired size
, please ask your designer to draw one. "Responsive" checkmark should be uncheck
ed when exporting icon.'", source: qrc://ui/index.js (29)
Mar 12 22:22:20 maude gnome-session[25678]: [0312/222220.925341:INFO:CONSOLE(66
)] "Updated model size: 475149", source: qrc://ui/index.js (66)
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude bluetoothd[1233]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.607 pa
th=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude bluetoothd[1233]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.607 pa
th=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[24282]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 26498 (kill).
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Mar 12 22:22:24 maude systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
Mar 12 22:22:28 maude org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[25520]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:26540): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
```

I had a bit of work in docker to do before I shutdown to hopefully put off this error occuring and it has happened again:

https://pastebin.com/wk1TnSuX

```
2020-03-13 06:59:32 ~                                                
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            11G        1.6G        8.1G         72M        1.9G        9.5G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G

2020-03-13 06:59:43 ~                                                
$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=79c1eda3-903c-4a32-8bc3-a40c90f86f7c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Something is calling fsck to run. Have you checked crontab https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-display-list-all-jobs-in-cron-crontab/ ? Also USB attached drives are slower and more vulnerable to failure. Why are you using an external SSD while leaving the PC up for days at a time?

Comment: Honestly it gets left up for days out of foolishness. I should shutdown but sometimes I'm in the middle of something and mean to return to something. But would that be the cause of this?  Only cron I see I expect that run fine elsewhere.

Comment: The 'Could not load' errors point to a problem with the drive. Move that SSD into the PC where it is attached to a SATA-III port and let us know if the problem persists, for it sure looks like your USB-SATA adapter is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Is this a vanilla 16.04 system? I'll bet not. How do you have GNOME on this system? This looks like a memory or swap issue. Do you even have a swap? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I think it is vanilla but it wasn't me that set it up (16.04 LTS). edited question with what you wanted.

Comment: @K7AAY I currently don't have the option to move it off of the USB but I have another cable I can try tomorrow.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema sorry I've not responded sooner. update in the question

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini Thanks for the update. However, the dmidecode output didn't give me all of the info that I was looking for. Please do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. It should be version 3.08. If not, you can get the newer version at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/by/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/ideapad-y510p-notebook/downloads/ds100556

Comment: @heynnema output: 74CN44WW(V3.05)
But I am reluctant to update it. I will see if I can boot on a different machine and reproduce the error. Oh and I did try a different SATA/USB cable and it didn't help. I looked through dpkg.log and the chrome install says amd64 a lot and this is an i7: https://pastebin.com/FaYipDMC

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini I've updated my answer. After good backups, do consider the BIOS update.

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini Status please... did you run memtest yet?

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini Status please...

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your logs, and reviewing your problem(s) description, it's difficult to identify any one cause. The errors are all over the place.

The system does not look like a stock 16.04 system, as I see references to gnome-session, and if memory serves me, that didn't come around until a much later system.

Before I recommend a CLEAN INSTALL of Ubuntu, lets check a few things.

**Memory**

Then, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**BIOS**

Let's check your BIOS version. Do `sudo dmidecode -t 1,2` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and add that output to your question. Tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

- **Update #1**: You have version 74CN44WW (V3.05). The latest BIOS for your Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P is version 74CN47WW (V3.08), and can be downloaded [here.](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/by/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/ideapad-y510p-notebook/downloads/ds100556) Do important file backups before updating the BIOS.